# How to get grails timestamp into variable

Tags: grails, time

After getting value froma query I want to set to a variable

```
println(Termin.endTime.getClass());
// class java.sql.Timestamp
```

This doesn't work:

```
Timestamp oldTime = Termin.endTime;
```

Which data type should I use?

Comment: What you mean with *doesn't work*? Do you have any exception on setting value?

Comment: : unable to resolve class Timestamp

Comment: did you import `java.sql.Timestamp` class?

Comment: It works now. Thank you. Post something so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import such class before use:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp

Timestamp oldTime = Termin.endTime;
```